# How to change the value of a python function variable for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

Given the following hypothetical code, how can I change the value of the variables `discount` and `is_active` so I can test the function `price_discount` for different expected return values?

`discounts.py`

```
import active_member

#returns a 20% discount value for active members 
def price_discount(price, membership_id):
    discount = 0.2
    is_active = active_member(membership_id)
    if is_active:
        price_discount = price * discount
    else:
        price_discount = 0

    return price_discount
```

`test_discounts.py`

```
import discounts

def test_price_discount():
    test = discounts.price_discount(50.00, 'D01910')
    assert test == some_expected_value
```

Comment: You can't, they are local variables in the `price_discount` function that are not accessible from outside (they don't even exist if the function is not running).

Comment: If the discount can be changed, it should be a function parameter, which will make it easy to test. If it can't, there's no reason to test it with anything other than `0.2`.

Comment: Did you mean `return price_discount`, perhaps?

Comment: If you need to test code with a different value of `discount`, it should be a parameter, not a hard-coded local variable. You can control the value of `is_active` by either passing a known inactive membership id, or by mocking `active_member` to return false.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html)

Your code should look like this:

```
import discounts


parameters = [
    { 
        "price": 50, 
        "membership": "D01910",
        "expected_value": 0
    },
    { 
        "price": 1, 
        "membership": "A",
        "expected_value": 0
    },
    { 
        "price": 2, 
        "membership": "B",
        "expected_value": 0
    }
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("parameter", parameters)
def test_price_discount(parameter):
    actual_value = discounts.price_discount(parameter['price'], parameter['membership'])
    assert actual_value == parameter["expected_value"]
```